# Hiding Sheet in Workbook from certain people

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, google-sheets

I've started tampering with Google sheets recently.  I cant seem to get the following script to actually do what I was hoping it would.  Ideally I want it to allow certain users read/write access and certain users the inability to even see the sheet.  I thought it would be possible but currently anyone can see the sheet.

```
function onOpen() {
  var adminUsers = ['chris.dan.rios@gmail.com']

  if (adminUsers.indexOf(Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail()) >= 0) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Admin').showSheet()
  }

  if (Users.indexOf(Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail()) >= 0) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Admin').hideSheet()
  }
}
```

Comment: and you are doing this with javascript?

Comment: Sorry, this is not how StackOverflow works. Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and read [Ask] to learn how to use this site effectively.  You have given us zero context in which to understand what you're asking.  All we can glean is that you're working with some sort of spreadsheet but it's not Excel.  Other than that we have no idea what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Google Sheets allows you to set permissions and hide without having to code anything. Simple select the drop down arrow on the sheet:

[image]

Those people you provide edit permissions will be able to find the hidden sheet(s), those without edit permissions will not be able to see the hidden sheet(s).

I hope this helps.